# how to edit xml using condition from value of other elements

Tags: java, xml, talend

I'm trying to edit an XML file by changing values of some elements based on the value of other elements but i dont seem to get through. I'm using talend although i'm abit new but atleast I've been able to read and output the XML file and can do some minor changes to element values although changes based on some condition i explain below is failing. Below is the XML and code I'm using in the condition:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ZipBill>
<NonUsage>
<Details Service="Mobile"  Lines="1"  Amount="10000" />
<Details Service="Landline"  Lines="1"  Amount="10000" />
</NonUsage>
<Usage>
<Details Service="Mobile"  Amount="191084" />
<Details Service="Landline"  Amount="73544" />
</Usage>
<WithoutTax>
<Details  Description="Total before Tax" Amount="284628" />
</WithoutTax>
<TotalTax>
<Details  Description="VAT(18%)" Amount="51233" />
<Details  Description="Excise Duty(12%)-GSM" Amount="31755" />
<Details  Description="Excise Duty(5%)-Fixed line" Amount="0" />
</TotalTax>
<TotalAmount>
<Details  Description="Total Inclusive Tax" Amount="367616" />
</TotalAmount>
</ZipBill>
```

Now what i;m trying to do is to change the amount value in the `<TotalTax>` tag where element is `<Details  Description="Excise Duty(5%)-Fixed line" Amount="0" />` and make it 0.05*amount value in the usage tag where element is `<Details Service="Landline"  Amount="73544" />` and where element is `<Details  Description="Excise Duty(12%)-GSM" Amount="31755" />` and make it 0.05*amount value in the usage tag where element is `<Details Service="Mobile"  Amount="191084" />`. in other words i would like to search for amount value in `<Details>` under `<usage>` where `Service="Landline"` and multiply it by 0.12 and then replace amount in in `<Details>` under `<TotalTax>` where `Description="Excise Duty(5%)-Fixed line"` and where `Service="Mobile"` and multiply it by 0.12 and then replace amount in in `<Details>` under `<TotalTax>` where `Description="Excise Duty(12%)-GSM"`. 
I defined three variables in talend to do theat replacement however i get duplicate fields in the xml. Any ideas on how i can modify these variables or any other option would be helpful.
Variables I used:

```
amount_fixed = [row6.ZipBill:/ZipBill/Usage/Details/@Service].toString().toLowerCase().contains("landline") ? Integer.parseInt([row6.ZipBill:/ZipBill/Usage/Details/@Amount])*0.12 : 0

amount_mobile = [row6.ZipBill:/ZipBill/Usage/Details/@Service].toString().toLowerCase().contains("mobile") ? Integer.parseInt([row6.ZipBill:/ZipBill/Usage/Details/@Amount])*0.12 : 0  

Tax_amount = [row4.ZipBill:/ZipBill/TotalTax/Details/@Description].toString().toLowerCase().contains("excise") && [row4.ZipBill:/ZipBill/TotalTax/Details/@Description].toString().toLowerCase().contains("fixed")  ? Var.amount_fixed : [row4.ZipBill:/ZipBill/TotalTax/Details/@Description].toString().toLowerCase().contains("excise") && [row4.ZipBill:/ZipBill/TotalTax/Details/@Description].toString().toLowerCase().contains("gsm")  ? Var.amount_mobile : Integer.parseInt([row4.ZipBill:/ZipBill/TotalTax/Details/@Amount])
```

The wrong output i get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ZipBill>
<NonUsage>
<Details Service="Mobile" Lines="1" Amount="10000"></Details>
<Details Service="Mobile" Lines="1" Amount="10000"></Details>
<Details Service="Landline" Lines="1" Amount="10000"></Details>
<Details Service="Landline" Lines="1" Amount="10000"></Details>
</NonUsage>
<Usage>
<Details Service="Mobile" Amount="191084"></Details>
<Details Service="Mobile" Amount="191084"></Details>
<Details Service="Landline" Amount="73544"></Details>
<Details Service="Landline" Amount="73544"></Details>
</Usage>
<WithoutTax>
<Details Description="Total before Tax" Amount="284628"></Details>
<Details Description="Total before Tax" Amount="284628"></Details>
</WithoutTax>
<TotalTax>
<Details Description="VAT(18%)" Amount="51233.0"></Details>
<Details Description="VAT(18%)" Amount="51233.0"></Details>
<Details Description="Excise Duty(12%)-GSM" Amount="22930.079999999998"> 
</Details>
<Details Description="Excise Duty(12%)-GSM" Amount="0.0"></Details>
<Details Description="Excise Duty(12%)-Fixed line" Amount="0.0"></Details>
<Details Description="Excise Duty(12%)-Fixed line" Amount="8825.279999999999"></Details>
</TotalTax>
<TotalAmount>
<Details Description="Total Inclusive Tax" Amount="367616"></Details>
<Details Description="Total Inclusive Tax" Amount="367616"></Details>
</TotalAmount>
</ZipBill>
```